# Is it possible to drag+drop a file from the browser to the desktop, causing a download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have an app that stores files and uses drag+drop to upload them. Is there a way I can drag+drop to download the file to my desktop instead of having to click "download." Basically, the opposite of drag+drop upload.

Comment: If that was possibly I would imagine you would have to write a browser extension.

Comment: Actually, it's possible with Chrome: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout

Comment: @raymi link is broken by me. Can you please provide a new link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to be able to set a download path, if nothing else, which no browsers allow you to do.  It's possible with a plugin, but not straight JS.

Comment: Follow up question - would you suggest a browser plugin to achieve this, which means I would have to create a plugin for every browser or some type of desktop integration?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest trying, to be honest.  It's non-standard behavior and nobody is going to try it unless you give them instructions.

Yes, you'd need a different plugin in every browser.

Comment: False -- it is (now) possible to do this. Chrome has a method (see below answer) and it appears Firefox requires an extension (http://superuser.com/questions/758797/downloading-files-with-drag-and-drop)

Comment: @Abacus -- This question is ___four and a half years old___.  Anyone seeing this should realize that technology is ever-changing and that an answer this old has little value.  Please don't add random noise, not to mention down-voting an answer simply because it's obsolete... sheesh

Answer (score 7):

The html5rocks and cssninja are ok, but I think way overkill for quick answers. Here is a simple example of using drag events from something, including to download files.

```
<style>
div { background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; float: left; clear: both; }
</style>
<div id="uiLinkText"           draggable="true">Drag <b>Text</b> to a text editor </div>
<div id="uiLinkHyperlink"      draggable="true">Drag <b>Hyperlink</b> to address bar </div>
<div id="uiLinkUrlDownload"    draggable="true">Drag <b>Url Download</b> to file system </div>
<div id="uiLinkStaticDownload" draggable="true">Drag <b>Static Download</b> to file system </div>
<script>
document.getElementById('uiLinkText').ondragstart = function(event){
  // plain text, for dropping into text editor
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411481/ to read about this.');
}
document.getElementById('uiLinkHyperlink').ondragstart = function(event){
  // URL, for dropping into the browser's address bar
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/uri-list', 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411481/');
}
document.getElementById('uiLinkUrlDownload').ondragstart = function(event){
  // file download contents, for dropping into a file system
  event.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', 'text/plain:SourceQuestion.html:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411481/')
}
document.getElementById('uiLinkStaticDownload').ondragstart = function(event){
  var textToWrite = 'file contents here';
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], { type: 'text/xml' });
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  // file download contents, for dropping into a file system
  event.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', 'text/plain:Static.txt:' + url)
}
</script>
```

Warning: While this worked fine for me in Chrome locally (in Windows 7), when I tried putting it on jsfiddle for a linke, the "Static Download" did not work, and the "Url Download" crashed Google Chrome.

As with most drag-and-drop, it does not work with MSIE 9, I have not tried 10+ or Firefox.

Comment: Works nicely in Chrome and Opera. Doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported in Google Chrome only.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-desktop-dnd-out
For example it is implemented in Gmail.

None of any other browsers support this behavior.

Comment: Demo from http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout works at least in Firefox 31.4 under Linux.

Comment: There's a lot to read and sort through in the tutorials -- here is the minimum viable code to demonstrate how this works: <a href="dummyLinkName" id="uiDragTest" draggable="true" ondragstart="(event || window.event).dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', 'text/plain:DestinationFileName.html:http://google.com')">Drag Me</a>

Comment: Link is broken. Use the [Webarchive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170306133316/https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) or the [new link](https://web.dev/box-dnd-download/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i tried on Floorp, which is a firefox-based browser and i use KDE Plasma on my computer and dragging it to the file manager causes it to download like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L5h8.png)

Comment: This question is asking if it is possible to use drag+drop from the browser to the file manager. While your answer technically addresses this, I'm not sure it would be useful to someone looking for the functionality the questions asks.

Surmising from the other answers, the drag+drop feature is available on Chrome, but requires an extension on Firefox. Because your using a browser that is a version of Firefox, Floorp probably has some sort of extension which allows the drag+drop functionality.

While this is well and good, this doesn't answer the question, and is really just confirming you nee