# How to Download file with Drag from Website to Desktop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The scenario is, I have already implemented **Upload** functionality with simple Drag and Drop. I am using **REACT DND** package for this.

Now I want to implement the inverse functionality.

Users will be able to **Download** file when they drag the Download Link to their Desktop/OS.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411481/212869 (seems to suggest that you cant, or its very browser specific)

Comment: First, you need to know if it is possible with `React DND` to listen for a drop for an element outside the web window which I do not think is possible. Hence, I recommend you find another way, for instance, to create a PC-like component that if any link was dropped in would download it directly!